# People Results and Thumbnail previews not working in Fast Search Server for SharePoint 2010

Tags: fast-search, ssl, certificate

My site uses SSL.

I am getting the following error in the Application log:

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:

Subject Name: CN=www.mycompany.net, OU=Consulting, O=mycompany, L=MyCity, S=GA, C=US
Issuer Name: CN=threewill, DC=mycompany, DC=com
Thumbprint: E377F928436B8913D21EBE218F17A4FC04A17DD9

Errors:

 The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority.
```

We are using a Domain Certificate

I've added this certificate to the Trusted Root Certification. I've also added to SharePoint under the Security, Manage Trust area in Central Administration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the AAMs set up for the My Site Host?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 shared service applications related to fast.  For People search, you want to create a content source under the "Query SSA" associated with FAST.  You can use the sps3://mysite.com or sps3s://mysite.com protocol depending upon whether you are using ssl.

Based on what I have seen so far, document thumbnails will NOT work with ssl but will work without it.